# Multitenancy and Subdomains in Orchard

Tags: subdomain, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, multi-tenant

Crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/455071

I'm using Orchard 1.6.1.

Say my first site is called domain.com. I tried to create a new tenant and put the beta.domain.com as the Host with no URL prefix (seeing that it is Optional).

The url http://beta.domain.com is shown and when I try to Set Up, it doesn't show anything. I tried to remove the subdomain and enter a prefix which resulted in http://domain.com/beta. It worked, however, I would very much prefer a subdomain as shown/detailed here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-multi-tenant-orchard-site

Do I have to set it up in my DNS server?

Any piece of advise or information would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an IIS server, you will need to have your beta.domain.com point at it and then add a binding to your website in iis of beta.domain.com for it to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using shared hosting and you don't have access to IIS. Then you should use Domain Aliases (in Plesk) rather than setting the DNS. It would make your Orchard CMS on your primary domain serve the tenant site.

Example: You want to add a tenant site on tenant.mysite.com then you should add a domain alias **tenant.mysite.com** to **mysite.com** domain. Don't forget to check the **Web** option if using Plesk.

In case of you have access to IIS, you need to add binding to your primary domain.